# radio button in jquery mobile is not showing

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am a newbie in jquery mobile. Never learn before just learning through the webs.

There's some questions that I would like to ask.

My radio button is showing however, there is no radio button 'circle'

Below is part of my codes:

```
                                     <text>Rating:</text>                      
foreach(var item in db.Query(rating)){
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-iconpos="right">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" >
<p> <input type="radio" name="question_@row.Question_id" id="question_@row.Question_id" value="@item.Option_description" checked="checked" />
                <label for="question_@row.Question_id">@item.Option_description</label>
                      </p></fieldset>
            </div>
var count= i+1;
```

**it is actually calling out the rating (very/good/fair/poor) from the database and loop for every questions that are also in the database**

Comment: What does it mean that there is no radio button 'circle'? Also, how are you using conditional statements in your html?

Comment: because I'm also using ASP.NET, razor and html in microsoft web matrix.

 i need to get the questions and ratings out from the database. Thus, using conditional statements. 

my radio buttons are not working as in not showing in terms of jquery mobile radio buttons but rather the html radio buttons.

Comment: Good to know the technologies that you are using, but there is still not enough clear information here.  Try posting more of your relevant code to clarify. Who knows what `var count=i + 1` is for...